# Disable comments in nodes specific taxonomy terms are attached to

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, comments

I know it is really easy to disable comments if your content is organized by content type, but what if it is organized by taxonomy, is it possible to disable comments on all nodes with, say, the term 'news' attached to them? If so, how?

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out as well...

Answer (score 3):

For anyone not already a seasoned Rules user, here are detailed steps / a worked example for @Wheelz's approach.

This answer shows you how to enable comments when a specific taxonomy term is present and to disable them when that taxonomy term is absent. As per @Wheelz's answer it requires the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules). These steps have been tested against [7.x-2.2](http://drupal.org/node/1711652).

1. Create a new Rule called, e.g. 'Enable comments when tagged blog'
2. Add an event of the `Before saving content` type (use the 'React on event' dropdown and under the subdivision *Node*, select `Before saving content`). Save.
3. Add a condition to test for the presence of the taxonomy field that will control whether comments are allowed.

   - Add a condition of the `Entity has field` type (use the 'Select the *condition* to add' dropdown and under the subdivision *Entities*, select `Entity has field`)
   - Select `node (saved content)` from the 'Data selector' dropdown. (Or type `node` into the 'Data selector' field.) (Don't be tempted by the `node:... (saved content)` option. It's not what is needed here.) *This specifies the type of entity for which you want to check for the presence of a field. In this case we want to check for nodes.*
   - Select the field to check for. The dropdown will give you a list of machine names (lower case and with underscores), e.g a field labelled 'Tags' might have the machine name `field_tags`. (If necessary look up the machine name for the relevant field in your the 'Manage Fields' tab of the relevant content type(s).)
   - Save
4. Add a condition to test for the taxonomy term that will **enable** comments.

   - If your taxonomy field can only have one value, then select a condition of the `Data comparison` type. Otherwise select a condition of the `List contains item` type.
   - Select the field to test using the 'Data selector' drop down. This is a two step process. First select `node:... (saved content)`. When you do this, the dropdown items change. Select `node:<your field's machine name - but with dashes not underscores>`, e.g. `node:field-tags`. (Don't be tempted by `node:field-tags:... (Tags)` - that's not what is needed here.)
   - Continue
   - If the next page isn't showing a 'Value' dropdown, click on the 'Switch to the direct input mode' button.
   - Use the 'Value' dropdown to select the taxonomy term for **enabling** comments, e.g. 'Blog'.
   - Save
5. Add an action that will enable comments

   - Add an action of the 'Set a data value' type.
   - Use the 'Data selector' to select the comment mode, This is a two step process. First select `node:... (saved content)`. When you do this, the dropdown items change. Select `node:comment (Comments allowed)`. Alternatively, you can directly enter `node:comment` into the 'Data selector' field. *If you let you let your mouse hover over `node:comment (Comments allowed)' entry in the dropdown you will see a helpful tip:* Whether comments are allowed on this node: 0 = no, 1 = closed (read only), 2 = open (read/write). *This helps with the next step.*
   - Continue
   - If the next page isn't showing a 'Value' field, click on the 'Switch to the direct input mode' button.
   - Enter `2` into the 'Value' field. This sets comments to 'Open (read/write)'.

The rule just created will switch on comments when the chosen taxonomy term is present. But if that taxonomy term is later removed the comments will still be open. To turn off comments when the taxonomy term is absent, first clone the rule just made and then make a couple of small tweaks.

1. From the main Rules configuration page, click the ‘clone’ link for the rule you have just created, e.g. 'Enable comments when tagged blog'
2. Change the name of the rule, e.g. to ‘Disable comments when not tagged blog’. Save changes.
3. Edit the ‘List contains item’ condition.

   - Check the ‘Negate’ box. *If the original condition succeeded, i.e. evaluated as TRUE, when the Tags field included the term ‘Blog’, this modified condition will succeed only when the Tags field does not include that term.*
   - Save.
4. Edit the ‘Set a data value’ action. Replace the value `2` with `0`. Save.

This second rule switch off comments when the chosen taxonomy term is absent.

**Note:** if a 'List contains item' gives an `Error: The data type of the configured argument does not match the parameter's list requirement` error, then your term reference field is set to allow only one value. You will need to delete the `List contains item` condition and replace it with a `Data comparison` condition instead. In the complementary case where `Data comparison` condition is used when a `List contains item` condition is needed, errors will be generated when the rule is run and the rule will not work.

[image: An enable rule will look something like this]

Answer (score 2):

Use Rules to check if a piece of content has a term on 'before saving content' and if so disable comments?

You need to create an action set component to set the node:comment value to 0 then call that as the action in your rule.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up copying comment-wrapper.tpl.php to the theme folder, wrapping everything in an if condition that checked for a `$skip_all` variable. Then, in `mytheme_preprocess_comment_wrapper`, I checked if $vars['node'] fit the conditions to hide the comments (`$node->type` was enough for me, but you can check `$node->taxonomy`). If it did, I set `$vars['skip_all'] = TRUE;`